# Import range script timeout

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

SO of late my importrange formulas have been collapsing so I decided to give the script version a try. I have a google script I got. The logic flow makes a lot of sense but when executing, it just runs endlessly without any output. Finally, it gives a timeout error at the end. I tried adding `SpreadsheeetApp.flush()` but it didn't work either. Here is the script below. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssA');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Source spreadsheet');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssB');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Target Spreadsheet'); 

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};
```

Comment: Which line is it timing out on? You can view this in the execution transcripts in script editor, or add `console.log` statements after each step and then review the Stackdriver logs. I recommend logging, as you can keep information about more than one execution. You might end up needing to do this in smaller batches.

Comment: Turned out that the issue was the permissions settings in the new Team Drive set....very annoying!

Comment: Add your solution to the issue, along with relevant resources you used to discover/the solution, into an answer and provide it. You'll be able to accept it then